# Open SmoothStreamingMediaElement fullscreen

Tags: silverlight, fullscreen

i wanna open a SmoothStreamingMediaElement in fullscreen and can't use the video brush as it takes mediaelement UI type so i tried to remove the element from it's grid to new grid but in that case it reload and replay the movie
is there anyway to move the control without removing and adding 
or there are other options to open it in fullscreen 
that's the code i am using

```
videoWindow.Children.Remove(mediaElement);
FullScreenGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
FullScreenGrid.Children.Add(mediaElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

You proberly found a solution by now, but maybe somebody else will find this.

I had the same problem as you and ended up using this simple class:

```
public class ExtendedSmoothStreamingElement : SmoothStreamingMediaElement
    {
        #region MediaElement (DependencyProperty)

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MediaElementProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MediaElement", typeof (MediaElement), typeof (ExtendedSmoothStreamingElement), null);

        public MediaElement MediaElement
        {
            get { return (MediaElement) GetValue(MediaElementProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MediaElementProperty, value); }
        }

        #endregion

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            MediaElement = (MediaElement)GetTemplateChild("MediaElement");
        }
    }
```

It exposes the inner `MediaElement` used by the `SmoothStreamingMediaElement`.

Another thing is that you can not set the `SmoothStreamingMediaElement.Visiblity` property to collapsed and play a video, like you can with the normal `MediaElement`.